# What if method has yield inside, but a block wasn't passed to it?

Tags: ruby, block, yield

What happens if you use a method that has a yield, without passing a block to it?

```
class SomeClass < Array
    def some_method
        yield(self[i])
    end
end

a = SomeClass.new
a.some_method
```

And is there a way to set a default behavior: give to the method default block to run, if other is not given?

Comment: you can check if `block_given?`. `block_given?` will check if block passed to yield.

Comment: branch on `block_given?`. If it's given, yield to it, else run default behaviour.

Comment: BTW, subclassing array is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Sergio I did that, to be able to use self[i] like in arrays, but messed up my concept.

Comment: `i` is an undefined local variable. @Sergio's stern admonition about subclassing `Array` applies to most, if not all, of Ruby's built-in classes. The reasons are covered [here](http://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Kernel#block_given?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F) to determine if a block is passed and take the appropriate action.

```
class SomeClass < Array
  def some_method
    if block_given?
      yield(self[i])
    else
      # not given
    end
  end
end
```

That means you can also have a default action if the block is not passed.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thank you!

Comment: does #block_given? work when a proc is passed?